# VC++ Linker complaining about a library which is not specified in the project file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost, cmake

I am getting this error in a CMake-generated .vcproj:

```
Performing Pre-Link Event...
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.lib'
```

Apart from the fact the library is called `boost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.lib`, I cannot find any reference to this in the .vcproj at all. Either in the Linker/input section, the generated command line, or even searching the .vcproj file in a text editor.

What could be going on, and how can I investigate the problem better? Is there a way to get the linker to tell me where it is finding a reference to `libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.lib` in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost uses auto-linking with Visual Studio so you don't have to explicitly link in any boost libraries. You can define `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to disable this feature, but I wouldn't recommend this, it works really well in my experience.

You can use `#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")` in Visual Studio to autolink libraries. If you take a look at boost/config/auto_link.hpp you'll see it being used.

In your case it is looking for the static version of boost thread and it might be that you didn't build that version when building boost. By specifying `--build-type=complete` in the `b2` options, you can ensure that both static and dynamic versions of the boost libraries are built. In that case you won't have to worry which version is auto-linked.

Comment: I think I have it set up so libs do need explicitly mentioning... no BOOST_HOME as I have multiple versions for different projects. However... this doesn't seem to answer the question when no other projects are complaining... do you mean it uses boost and that automatically triggers linking of the lib?

Answer (score 0):

`boost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.lib` is an *import* library for `boost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.dll`. However, it seems that you link CRT statically, so boost auto-link feature attempts to link static Boost libraries as well, and it seeks the *static* Boost.Thread library, named `libboost_thread-vc90-mt-1_44.lib`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369613/boost-install-windows-msvc-10-0-example-cpp-fails-to-link) for more details.

Comment: I haven't build boost, it came as a pre-built dependency with this project. However it might be that CRT setup is the problem here due to CMake perhaps.