# boost install windows msvc 10.0 -- example.cpp fails to link

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

Having downloaded boost 1.53.0 and cleanly executed the simplified install instructions on WinXP

> bootstart
>       
> .\b2

The libraries that were built were all of the form
libboost_xxxxx-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib
but I get linker errors since the linker is looking for libboost_xxxxx-vc100-mt-s-gd-1_53.lib. How do I get the -s (static) versions of libraries built? I assumed .lib are already all static but renaming them results in different errors.

When I compile the example.cpp program I get a linker error

```
$ cl /EHsc   -IC:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~1.0/VC/include -ID:/boost/boost_1_53_0 example.cpp   /link 
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

example.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:example.exe 
example.obj 
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s-1_53.lib'
```

If I copy libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_53.lib to libboost_regex-vc100-mt-s-1_53.lib (along with others it reports missing I get errors like this

```
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP100.dll) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) already defined in libcpmt.lib(xthrow.obj)
```

When I build with b2 --build-type=complete
D:\boost\boost_1_53_0>.\b2 --build_type=complete

> Building the Boost C++ Libraries.
>
> Performing configuration checks
>
> ```
> - 32-bit                   : yes
> - x86                      : yes
> - has_icu builds           : no warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components. note: to enable them, add
> ```
>
> "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
>       - iconv (libc)             : no
>       - iconv (separate)         : no
>       - icu                      : no
>       - icu (lib64)              : no
>       - gcc visibility           : no
>       - long double support      : yes warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library. note: to enable MPI support,
>   add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam. note: to suppress this message,
>   pass "--without-mpi" to bjam. note: otherwise, you can safely ignore
>   this message. warning: No python installation configured and
>   autoconfiguration note: failed.  See
>   http://www.boost.org/libs/python/doc/building.html note: for
>   configuration instructions or pass --without-python to note: suppress
>   this message and silently skip all Boost.Python targets
>
> Component configuration:
>
> ```
> - atomic                   : building
> - chrono                   : building
> - context                  : building
> - date_time                : building
> - exception                : building
> - filesystem               : building
> - graph                    : building
> - graph_parallel           : building
> - iostreams                : building
> - locale                   : building
> - math                     : building
> - mpi                      : building
> - program_options          : building
> - python                   : building
> - random                   : building
> - regex                    : building
> - serialization            : building
> - signals                  : building
> - system                   : building
> - test                     : building
> - thread                   : building
> - timer                    : building
> - wave                     : building
> ```
>
> ...patience... ...patience... ...patience... ...patience... ...found
>   7117 targets...
>
> The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!
>
> The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:
>
> ```
> D:/boost/boost_1_53_0
> ```
>
> The following directory should be added to linker library paths:
>
> ```
> D:\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib
> ```

I still do not see the libraries

```
> D:\boost\boost_1_53_0>dir D:\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib  Volume in
> drive D is DATA  Volume Serial Number is A065-A7DE
> 
>  Directory of D:\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib
> 
> 03/12/2013  11:26 AM    <DIR>          . 03/12/2013  11:26 AM    <DIR>
> .. 03/12/2013  10:36 AM             7,978
> libboost_atomic-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:26 AM           
> 57,152 libboost_atomic-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM      
> 355,990 libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:26 AM        
> 1,493,080 libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM   
> 2,710 libboost_context-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:27 AM         
> 5,436 libboost_context-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM      
> 626,878 libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:27 AM     
> 2,097,458 libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM
> 5,482 libboost_exception-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:27 AM       
> 39,434 libboost_exception-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM   
> 871,780 libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:27 AM    
> 4,306,464 libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:38
> AM         5,840,912 libboost_graph-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013 
> 10:28 AM        14,463,054 libboost_graph-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib
> 03/12/2013  10:38 AM           418,180
> libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:28 AM        
> 1,272,374 libboost_iostreams-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:39 AM
> 6,897,100 libboost_locale-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:29 AM      
> 22,057,274 libboost_locale-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:41 AM  
> 809,360 libboost_math_c99-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:31 AM      
> 2,903,758 libboost_math_c99-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:41 AM 
> 810,648 libboost_math_c99f-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:31 AM     
> 2,898,286 libboost_math_c99f-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:41 AM
> 787,332 libboost_math_c99l-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:31 AM     
> 2,863,258 libboost_math_c99l-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:39 AM
> 5,859,300 libboost_math_tr1-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:29 AM    
> 14,516,786 libboost_math_tr1-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:40 AM
> 6,145,246 libboost_math_tr1f-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:30 AM   
> 15,051,100 libboost_math_tr1f-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:40
> AM         5,807,100 libboost_math_tr1l-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013 
> 10:30 AM        14,407,024 libboost_math_tr1l-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib
> 03/12/2013  10:44 AM           219,580
> libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc100-mt-1_53.l ib 03/12/2013  10:34 AM     
> 1,239,714 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc100-mt-gd-1_5
> 3.lib 03/12/2013  10:42 AM         6,461,312 libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-1_53.li b 03/12/2013  10:32 AM      
> 20,176,878 libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_53 .lib 03/12/2013 
> 10:42 AM            83,144 libboost_random-vc100-mt-1_53.lib
> 03/12/2013  10:32 AM           405,594
> libboost_random-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:37 AM       
> 10,593,312 libboost_regex-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:28 AM      
> 34,707,966 libboost_regex-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:43 AM   
> 11,509,722 libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:33
> AM        30,119,740 libboost_serialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.l ib
> 03/12/2013  10:44 AM         1,000,288
> libboost_signals-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:34 AM        
> 3,919,576 libboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36 AM  
> 83,030 libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:26 AM         
> 414,676 libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:44 AM     
> 10,382,950 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc100-mt-1_53. lib 03/12/2013 
> 10:34 AM        24,314,874 libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc100-mt-gd-1_
> 53.lib 03/12/2013  10:45 AM           978,672 libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:35 AM        
> 2,921,850 libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:45 AM   
> 177,274 libboost_timer-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:35 AM         
> 858,164 libboost_timer-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:45 AM      
> 11,293,008 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-1_5
> 3.lib 03/12/2013  10:35 AM        26,806,730 libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-mt-gd- 1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:46
> AM        47,173,122 libboost_wave-vc100-mt-1_53.lib 03/12/2013  10:36
> AM        99,093,052 libboost_wave-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib 03/12/2013 
> 10:43 AM         8,910,826 libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-1_53.lib
> 
> 03/12/2013  10:33 AM        20,527,762
> libboost_wserialization-vc100-mt-gd-1_53. lib 03/12/2013  11:26 AM   
> <DIR>          xx
>               56 File(s)    508,050,750 bytes
>                3 Dir(s)   8,116,432,896 bytes free
> 
> D:\boost\boost_1_53_0>
```

Comment: Add `--build-type=complete` to your `b2` invocation and all combinations of static/shared, debug/release, and single/multi-threaded variants will be built.

Comment: Note that .lib files are generated for DLLs too (and are used when you link against those DLLs). So a .lib file may be a static library, or it may just be a stub for linking against a DLL.

Comment: Thanks, adding --build-type=complete to your b2 invocation did the trick. And thanks for the FYI on .lib extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the naming convention of boost libraries [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#invoke-b2). And Boost.Build properties can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.properties).

So, if you need a static library that links CRT statically, invoke bjam like this:

```
b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 release threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static
```